# Custom ranking selection with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a 100x5 pandas dataframe with values ranging from 1 to 499.

```py
# seed for reproducability
np.random.seed(3)
sample = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 500, size = (100, 5)))
sample.columns = "X Y Z F V".split()
```

I want to select 10 rows from this dataframe, where for each column I select the rows corresponding the top 2 values for each of the columns (separately) and without duplicates.

If there are duplicates lets say for top 1st of column X and top 2nd of Y, then randomly keep one of them and the other one replace with the next biggest (top 3rd for X or top 3rd for Y -> randomly) and do it until there are no duplicate rows selected for any columns.

What I have so far

```py
# convert it to long format and use groupby to get top values and their index - ID
stacked = (
            sample
           .stack()
           .reset_index()
           .rename(columns = {"level_0": "ID", "level_1": "Feature", 0: "Value"})
           .set_index("ID")
          )

stacked.groupby("Feature").Value.nlargest(2)
```

Which gives me this

```
Feature ID  Value
F   37  489
F   32  481
V   19  497
V   22  497
X   25  495
X   32  491
Y   17  498
Y   22  496
Z   95  496
Z   45  489
```

It means, I need to select the rows based on ID values from that dataset. However, as you see, for column `V` and `Y`, `F` and `X` I have duplicate rows selected. I could not come up with the implementation of the logic with duplicates. I would be grateful for any help

One potential approach could be to select 5 rows per each column top values with `groupby.nlargest()` and from that dataframe select two as top as possible  rows per each column where there are no duplicates. Unfortunately, I do not know any pythonic ways of doing this:

```
    Feature ID  Value
0   F   37  489
1   F   32  481
2   F   65  474
3   F   82  470
4   F   66  467
5   V   19  497
6   V   22  497
7   V   11  489
8   V   98  486
9   V   15  484
10  X   25  495
11  X   32  491
12  X   99  490
13  X   76  487
14  X   93  486
15  Y   17  498
16  Y   22  496
17  Y   89  494
18  Y   68  493
19  Y   3   480
20  Z   95  496
21  Z   45  489
22  Z   62  488
23  Z   79  485
24  Z   22  484
```

Desirable result would be (there is randomality)

```py
    X   Y   Z   F   V
37  133 212 351 489 106
32  491 135 441 481 427
19  48  445 289 308 497
22  182 496 484 91  497
25  495 444 216 311 267
99  490 164 345 23  365
17  400 498 274 331 183
89  309 494 122 82  140
95  275 213 496 167 98
45  267 246 489 252 17
```

Maybe I explained the logic in a complex way, but if you look at dataset and desirable outcome, you might get more clue

EDIT:
fixed the desirable result, it contained duplicate

Comment: What if there is a same row corresponding to largest values in two or more column? For example consider the case where `V` and `Y` both have maximum corresponding to row with index `22`? Should the same row will be appended twice?

Comment: if there are potential duplicates in two ore more columns, then 1 is kept randomly, and others are replaced with the next biggest value (considering they do not overlap between each other) if there are still duplicates between the remaining two, then repeat the procedure

Comment: I think you'll need to do loops to check for duplicates after selecting the top two for each group consecutively.

Comment: in your desirable result is the row 32 repeated

Comment: Do you care about associativity/commutativity? That is, if you get wildly different answers depending on how you order the columns, does that both you?

Comment: No, it does not. Because data is randomly generated, columns will be switching places too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible way to approach the problem, where we use `set` to store the indices corresponding to top two largest values from each column

**Pseudocode**

- For every column in the dataframe

  - Drop the indices that are already selected from the previous columns
  - drop the duplicate values
  - Sort the values in descending order
  - Using set union (`|=`) add the indices corresponding to top 2 largest values in the current column

```
ix = set()
for c in df.columns:
    s = df[c].drop(ix).drop_duplicates().sort_values(ascending=False)
    ix |= set(s.index[:2])
```

---

```
>>> df.loc[ix]

      X    Y    Z    F    V
32  491  135  441  481  427
65  274  320  455  474  437
37  133  212  351  489  106
11  375   54    0  192  489
45  267  246  489  252   17
17  400  498  274  331  183
19   48  445  289  308  497
22  182  496  484   91  497
25  495  444  216  311  267
95  275  213  496  167   98
```

Comment: could you please explain the code? I would like to understand your approach

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution although it is not the most elegant:

```
indexes = []
while len(indexes) < 2 * len(sample.columns):
    new_df = sample.drop(index=indexes)
    if new_df.iloc[:, len(indexes) // 2].idxmax() not in indexes:
        indexes.append(new_df.iloc[:, len(indexes) // 2].idxmax())
sample.iloc[indexes]
```

Output:

```
>>> print(sample.iloc[indexes])

      X    Y    Z    F    V
25  495  444  216  311  267
32  491  135  441  481  427
17  400  498  274  331  183
22  182  496  484   91  497
95  275  213  496  167   98
45  267  246  489  252   17
37  133  212  351  489  106
65  274  320  455  474  437
19   48  445  289  308  497
11  375   54    0  192  489
```

Comment: both solutions do the job, yet I gave my checkmark for the other one, because it was more concise and cleaner